# fetch script from external server and add it in html files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

the JS script is present in an external server (https://altest.vlp.domain.com/e/8e2cd8c9/abcd) in the format of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){(function().....
1000+ lines
....
</script>
```

This script is for monitoring the logs it needs to be added in  of all HTML files.
How to call the JS code snippet from another server which already has  tag defined

tried:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://altest.vlp.domain.com/e/8e2cd8c9/abcd">` 
this throws below error because  external js file should not have script defined
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: "the JS script is present in an external server … in the format of" — no, it isn't. That's a 404 error document.

Comment: And `<script>` elements are for loading scripts. Not HTML documents with scripts embedded in them.

Comment: If I hit the URL it shows the script in that format. question is how to load the script which already has <script> tag defined. will you be able to answer for the original question

Comment: the URl is not poinitng .js file